# javac: file not found at public folder laravel

Tags: java, laravel, javac

Okay, I made a web app by Laravel and it has a part was written by java
this java part was written to compile java file and I put it in the public folder

I'm calling this java code from a controller and sending the file in args array like this:

```
exec("java -jar API/dist/API.jar " . "storage/assignments/submited/file.java", $output);
```

and from java like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac " + Assignment_dir);
```

This was fine on my computer on localhost but when I uploaded it on Digital Ocean Droplet it keeps giving me that

> javac: file not found: storage/assignments/submited/file.java Usage: javac use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: check for the folder structure, you are missing a few slashes

Comment: @Satya how ?!! it works on my localhost

Comment: go to submitted folder on digitalocean and run pwd , it will give you the exact location of file,java . Repeat the same process for dist folder . You will get absolute paths of both files which you need to substitute in exec command

Comment: @Satya I tried, but there's no point. I want to point something out, the jar file is working perfectly ... and the rest of API too on the same file but the problem when the jar file running javac